# Encrypt XML using AES/CBC/PKCS7

Tags: xml, apache, encryption, aes

I want to use Apach XMLCipher to encrypt using AES/CBC/PKCS7 padding. I would not find any way to do so. I believe XMLCipher does not provide this support.
Is there a neat way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just use XMLCipher.AES_128. It refers to the following URI:

```
http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc
```

So that takes care of the CBC mode. You can of course also go for the 192 or 256 bit variants of AES.

As for the padding mode, XML encryption seems to standardize on [ISO/IEC 10126 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#ISO_10126), which is almost - but not quite - PKCS#7 compatible padding. It is specified in the sub-paragraph of [paragraph 5.2 of the XML-enc specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/Overview.html#sec-Alg-Block). If you are using PKCS#7 unpadding during decryption you *are likely* to receive padding errors, depending on how the padding was performed during encryption.